Is the Book Shaar HaYichud a continuation of Shaar HaEmunah By the Mittler Rebbe?
BH
Hi in the Mittler Rebbes book translation on Sefaria translated by Rabbi Amiram Markel [1] it says that "it is through the delving of the concentration that one can come to the depth of the concept, until its very source in the depths of Chochmah and Binah. ([Through the above he is capable of] reaching the aspect of the upper Da’at which unites Chochmah and Binah, as was explained previously regarding the matter of the depth of the comprehension (Omek HaMoosag) of Binah."
Although where does it in Shaar HaYichud say before this that through deep consentration when one reaches the omek hamusag(depth of the concept) he is able to reach the aspect of the upper Daat which unites chochma and bina?
Does this mean it is mentioned before in Shaar HaEmunah as Shaar HaYichud comes right after Shaar Emunah in the Traditional Ner Mitzvah VeTorah [2] and the two are connected Shaar Yichud being a hemshech of Shaar HaEmunah?
Also if yes where does it mention this in Shaar HaEmunah?
[1] https://www.sefaria.org/The_Gate_of_Unity.1.46?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en
[2] https://hebrewbooks.org/16054

Just glancing at the Sefaria English translation of the section that you linked to. In my opinion, that translation leaves much to be desired. It does not represent the accurate meaning of the words of the Hebrew original.

The Mitteler Rebbe did intend for Sha'ar HaEmunah and Sha'ar HaYichud to be published together, as can be seen at the end of his introduction to Ner Mitzvah veTorah Or. I don't know if that means that one should be viewed as a "continuation" of the other, but that's also not really relevant here.
In the piece you cite, he's referring to what he wrote earlier in chapter 1 of Sha'ar HaEmunah, that the "depth of comprehension" represents the source of binah in chochmah i.e. the point of connection of the two.

Where does it say anything about the upper daas before that though since he calles the delving of the consentration maamik since it activates both chochma and bina

He explains there the connection of binah and chochmah at the point of omek hmusag, and tells (or reminds) you here that the point of connection of binah and chochmah is da'at elyon.

interesting btw I had a question here [1]  I think it was similar to this although its from the book of the Ramban do you think this is the same thing as whats going on here?

[1]https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/143997/is-there-an-explanation-in-chabad-of-the-story-of-how-ben-azai-was-sitting-and-s

This is the link ^

@David I'm afraid I'm not well versed enough in Chabad thought nor Iggeret HaKodesh (which, by the way, modern scholarship assumes was not authored by Ramban) to be able to answer that question.

Interesting who said this? and who do they say it was written by then?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nachmanides#Iggeret_ha-Kodesh No one is sure who actually wrote it
